# clearInterval() won't be triggered if setInterval() button is clicked multiple times

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I'm playing around with a Colour Generator app and I added a "disco" function which will trigger random colours to "flash" to the rythm of a song. By the way, you won't be able to hear it but it's "Turn down for what" :))

Everything works, but: If I click multiple times the "Disco" button, `setInterval()` will accelerate (which I don't mind, in fact I like it), but it won't be cleared no more once I decide to stop it by scrolling or swiping on mobile.

I read multiple similar questions here, but none had a similar problem, and I really have no clue of what I could do.

I'd like to make it accelerate if clicked multiple times, but I also want to be able to clear it.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button')
let body = document.querySelector('.body')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let disco = document.querySelector('.disco')
let song = document.querySelector('.song')

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
  + ')'

  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = 'rgb (' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
+ ')'

  button.style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'

  disco.style.display = 'none'
})

let dance = function() {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
  + ')'
  }

let dancing;
let stopping;

disco.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'
  dancing = setInterval(dance,300)

  stopping = setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(dancing)
    button.style.display = 'block'
    body.style.background = 'white'
    document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
   }, 15400)

  if(song.paused) {
    song.play()
    button.style.display = 'none'
  }
})


window.addEventListener('touchmove', ()=> {
  body.style.background = 'white'
  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = ''
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
  button.style.border = '1px solid black'

  clearInterval(dancing)
  clearTimeout(stopping)
  song.pause()
  song.currentTime = 0
  button.style.display = 'block'
  disco.style.display = 'block'
})
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.color {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scrollto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
  display: none;
}

.disco {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  border: .5px solid black;
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  padding-top: .1em;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="button">Generate Colour</h3>
    <p class="color"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <p class="scrollto">swipe on screen to reset</p>
  </div>

  <h3 class="disco">Disco</h3>
  <audio class="song" src="song.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: You only save one interval. If you start multiple by clicking the button multiple times, you're overwriting that one interval reference and are losing access to the other started intervals.

Comment: Every new call to `setInterval` overwrites the interval ID you store in the variable `dancing`, so you won’t be able to clear previously set intervals this way. Check if `dancing` is not undefined (or a basic check for true-ness should do as well) before you call setInterval, and if so, clear it at that point, before you create a new one.

Comment: @deceze ok so the better solution would be to "give up" the acceleration of the interval and to have just one. right? but in this case how can I avoid to overwriting when clicking multiple times?

Comment: hide the button ? xD after disco is on

Comment: @MuhammadUsman well that is an idea :))

Comment: Clear the old interval before overwriting it. And if you want the acceleration, keep track of how fast your current interval is, and when setting a new one (after clearing the old one), make it faster.

Comment: @CBroe this will allow me to accelerate it without overwriting others? or that option isn't possible?

Comment: @deceze oooh, gotcha! thanks!

Comment: btw, if you wanna have fun, mycolour.netlify.app :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you change the content of the `dancing` variable at each click. Means that at click 1 it will reference the setInterval1, at click 2 setInterval2 etc. then when you try to do `clearInterval` you actually clear only the last reference you created.

You can avoid it by simply clearing the old interval before to add a new one:

(I changed the stop event to right click, for example purpose )

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button')
let body = document.querySelector('.body')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let disco = document.querySelector('.disco')
let song = document.querySelector('.song')

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
  + ')'

  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = 'rgb (' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
+ ')'

  button.style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'

  disco.style.display = 'none'
})

let dance = function() {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
  + ')'
  }

let dancing;
let stopping;

disco.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'
  clearInterval(dancing);
  clearTimeout(stopping)
  dancing = setInterval(dance,300)

  stopping = setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(dancing)
    button.style.display = 'block'
    body.style.background = 'white'
    document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
   }, 15400)

  if(song.paused) {
    //song.play()
    button.style.display = 'none'
  }
})


window.addEventListener('contextmenu', ()=> {
  body.style.background = 'white'
  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = ''
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
  button.style.border = '1px solid black'

  clearInterval(dancing)
  clearTimeout(stopping)
  song.pause()
  song.currentTime = 0
  button.style.display = 'block'
  disco.style.display = 'block'
})
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.color {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scrollto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
  display: none;
}

.disco {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  border: .5px solid black;
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  padding-top: .1em;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="button">Generate Colour</h3>
    <p class="color"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <p class="scrollto">swipe on screen to reset</p>
  </div>

  <h3 class="disco">Disco</h3>
  <audio class="song" src="song.mp3"></audio>
```

**EDIT:**

From the comments, I see that you want to keep the accelerating effect:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button')
let body = document.querySelector('.body')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let disco = document.querySelector('.disco')
let song = document.querySelector('.song')

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
  + ')'

  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = 'rgb (' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
+ ')'

  button.style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'

  disco.style.display = 'none'
})

let dance = function() {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree
  + ')'
  }

let dancing;
let stopping;
let speed = 300;
const accFactor = 1.5;

disco.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'
  if(dancing) {
   clearInterval(dancing);
   clearTimeout(stopping);
    speed = speed/accFactor;
  }
  dancing = setInterval(dance,speed);

  stopping = setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(dancing)
    button.style.display = 'block'
    body.style.background = 'white'
    document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
   }, 15400)

  if(song.paused) {
    //song.play()
    button.style.display = 'none'
  }
})


window.addEventListener('contextmenu', ()=> {
  body.style.background = 'white'
  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = ''
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
  button.style.border = '1px solid black'

  clearInterval(dancing)
  clearTimeout(stopping)
  song.pause()
  song.currentTime = 0
  button.style.display = 'block'
  disco.style.display = 'block'
})
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.color {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scrollto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
  display: none;
}

.disco {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  border: .5px solid black;
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  padding-top: .1em;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="button">Generate Colour</h3>
    <p class="color"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <p class="scrollto">swipe on screen to reset</p>
  </div>

  <h3 class="disco">Disco</h3>
  <audio class="song" src="song.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: thank you very much, so basically I have to clear the interval on click also?

Comment: Yes, if not you create a memory leak by never clearing the old intervals that continue to execute forever

Comment: Well, it is not working fine and as expected, because you need to clear timeout as well in each click event, otherwise at the end of the timeout it will be shortened in next execution. So it will be buggy in the even click events. 